# What is a random point in the space of generalized functions $F=\{f|f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\}$？

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, distribution-theory

What is a random point in the space of generalized functions $F=\{f|f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R , \ \int_\mathbb R f=1 \}$？

In other words, what is a function-valued random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $F$ in the OP is not what is usually called the space of generalized functions. The latter would usually mean the spaces of Schwartz distributions $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. These have a natural topology called the strong topology and thus a Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$. A random element in these spaces is a distribution valued random variable $T$. Namely it is a $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B})$-measurable map $T:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})\ {\rm or}\ \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is some probability space.

Comment: Interesting! The distribution valued RV is exactly what I was looking for. Are there any books on this topic?

Comment: lookup first https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09326 unfortunately their "generalized random field" terminology is nonstandard but the presentation is quite pedagogical.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I do not understand 100% of your formulations. Is your $S'(\mathbb R)$ the Schwartz space? Would you mind to give the definition of $D'(R)$.

Comment: D(R) is the space of compactly supported infinitely differentiable functions and D'(R) is the space of distributions, i.e., its topological dual. S(R) is the Schwartz space of infinitely differentiable functions with rapid decay at infinity. S'(R) is also its dual, the space of temperate distributions. One has inclusions $D\subset S\subset S'\subset D'$. My formulation is pretty standard but can't be explained in a comment. See, e.g., https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/

Comment: This is very clear and standard! So I guess we could define the space of Schwartz distributions of Schwartz distributions (maybe $S(S(\mathbb R))$), and natural strong topology will exist?

Comment: @dodo: Yes but it's not that easy. Keywords: Hida distributions, Kondratiev triple, Borchers algebra. Essentially what you are trying to do leads to quantum field theory.

Comment: So the optimal action that I should take is to read a standard QFT textbook?

Comment: Hida and Meyer-Yan triples. YG Kondratiev, infinite dimensional analysis.